# prisma cascade delete a one-to-one mongoDB relationship

Tags: mongodb, prisma, prisma-graphql

Goal: When I delete `Lesson`, I want it to also delete its linked one-to-one `LessonCards` document.

The only pattern I've found so far that works is *updating* `Lesson` to delete its linked `LessonCards` which then cascades back up and deletes the `Lesson` I wanted to originally delete.

This seems hacky.

What can I do to fix my `prisma.schema` to solve this?

```
model Lesson {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title       String
  description String

  lessonCardsId String?      @unique @db.ObjectId
  lessonCards   LessonCards? @relation(fields: [lessonCardsId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model LessonCards {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  cards Card[]

  Lesson Lesson?
}
```

action:

```js
deleteLesson: (_, { id }) => {
  return prisma.lesson.update({
    where: {
      id: id,
    },
    data: {
      lessonCards: { delete: true },
    },
  });
},
```

note: it makes sense to me that the `Lesson` has a fkey to `LessonCards`, reversing the @relation would be confusing.